# Redirect to page with form fields filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models in my application:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :telephones
end

class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and in my form to user i have user's fields and link to new or edit telephones, something like this:

```
.panel.panel-default
  .panel-heading User
  .panel-body
    .row
      = f.input :name, wrapper_html: { class: "col-md-8" }
      = f.input :age, wrapper_html: { class: "col-md-4" }
    .row
      .col-md-4
        h4 Telefones
        - unless user.telephones.blank?
          table.table.table-borded
            thead
              tr
                th= Telephone.human_attribute_name(:title)
                th= Telephone.human_attribute_name(:number)
                th

            tbody
              - user.telephones.each do |telephone|
                tr
                  td= telephone.title
                  td= telephone.number
                td
                  = link_to(fa_icon("edit"), edit_telephone_path(telephone), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default") + " "
                  = link_to fa_icon("trash-o"), telephone_path(telephone), class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger",
                                                                              method: :delete,
                                                                              data: { confirm: t("titles.confirm") }
         = link_to(fa_icon("plus", text: "New"), new_telephone_path(), class: "btn btn-sm btn-success")
```

If I fill in the username and age field of the user and click in button New, my application redirect to Telephone form, and after create, redirect back to User form with telephone created, but the data of fields name and age are lost.
What i do this saving user data when click in button New and redirect user form filled after create telephone??

Comment: From a UX perspective, why does the user have to have 3 pages load just to sign up? Or did I misunderstand something? Why not just put a partial for the telephone fields on the sign up page, permit these parameters and do the validations in your registrations controller? Can you show your user `create` controller method and your telephone `create` controller method? Maybe we can abstract the telephone create method into a class and reuse it in user `create` method

Comment: redirect to edit and your form should be populated with data